# What is the correct approach for commiting changes to trunk from branch?

Tags: eclipse, svn, branching-and-merging

I had to add a new feature to a web project. So I created its branch and added the new feature in the branch and now my code is ready to go on production. But how do I merge it with trunk? What is the correct approach?

I am using subversion with eclipse.

Should I first merge my trunk code with branch code and commit it in branch? Or should I directly switch to trunk and start merging it with branch code?

Also, it would be very helpful if someone can tell me which option to use in eclipse for each step..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need in this situation is to [reintegrate](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate) your branch.

First, merge new changes from trunk into your branch and commit. It is good practice to run your tests (automatic or manual) before commit in this step to confirm that changes from trunk don't break your new feature. Then, switch to trunk and merge from branch to trunk in "reintegrate" mode to replicate your branch changes, and commit.

To understand the process I recommend you to try to perform these operations with command line `svn` tool, as decribed in [this guide](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate).

I assume you use [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) plugin in Eclipse, which is installed by default. Here is its merge dialog window. To merge from trunk use "URL" tab (perform merge in branch WC, specify trunk URL in "URL" field), to reintegrate branch - "Reintegrate" tab (perform merge in trunk WC, specify branch URL in "URL" field):

[image: Subversive merge dialog]

See description of other options in [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/merge_dialog.php).

Comment: I want to note that automatic merges in SVN 1.8 make `--reintegrate` parameter obsolete. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.reintegrate

Comment: So for a reintegrate I start the process by right-clicking on my trunk project or on my branch project?